# wso2 AS SSL error with the no default localhost certificate

Tags: ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-wsas

I’m trying to consume a secured web service hosted on WSO2 AS, so I created a new certificate in the existing wso2carbon.jks file of the server and add it to the client JVM cacerts but I’m getting this error:

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Nevertheless if I create a brand new wso2carbon.jks and overwrite the old one in the server after add the new certificate to the client JVM cacerts I can consume the secured service but other things in AS stop working like datasources, I tried adding the new certificate to the client-truststore.jks in the server, but datasource still don’t work. I’m working with AS 5.0.0
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by "other things in AS stop working like datasources"? Are they already created datasources and i assume you are using AS 5.2.1

Comment: I'm working with AS 5.0.0 as I told in my entrance; I had some datasources created for a few dataservices that were working well, when I overwrote the wso2carbon.jks with the one I had created and rebooted the server the created datasources disappeared and an error appeared when I tried to recreate them again, I switch back the older wso2carbon.jks and everything work fine again but I can’t consume the secured web service

Comment: I guess those datasource resources stored at registry and those resources getting encrypted when storing. Have you tried to create new datasource or try the scenario in a fresh pack where keystore is changed to new one from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your own certificate, you need to modify the WSO2 configuration files to point to your certificate. Basically, you need to modify `repository/conf/carbon.xml`, and `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`. In case of ESB, you need to modify `repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` as well. The changes needed are described in this [blog](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-add-new-keystore-to-carbon-4_3.html).

The error that you faced with data sources is because of the change of certificates. The reason is that, WSO2 encrypts the datasource passwords using the current keystore certificate at the time of datasource creation. To fix the error, you will need to remove your datasources, and re-add them. No need to re-create your data-services though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the host name(in the carbon.xml) of the AS?

1st Case:
In default wso2carbon.jks have its CN as localhost so you need to change the keystore if you are working with different host name or else you need to invoke hosted web service using localhost.

2nd Case:
If you changed(created and replaced) the wso2carbon.jks of the AS with a appropriate CN, you need to extract its public certificate and import it into cacerts, and client-truststore.jks of all other carbon servers which contact with AS.

HTH,

DarRay

Answer (score 0):

Your client is trying to check the domain name or IP of the server against the domain name or IP in the certificate to ensure that it is reaching the right server.  You need to create a new certificate to use that has a subject alternative name equal to the domain name or IP of the server, whichever the client is using to connect.

Comment: yes, that's what I did, I created a new jks with a pair of new keys, I replaced the wso2carbon.jks by the new one I had created, exported the certificate and added it  to the client JVM cacerts, so I could consume the secured web service,  but the created and working datasource of my dataservices stopped working

Comment: The problem is this: if I create a new key in the existing wso2carbon.jks with the right CN and the extension for the IP, export the certificate and add it to the client JVM cacerts I receive: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present, but If create a new wso2carbon.jks I can consume the secured web service but the datasource of my dataservices stopped working

Comment: What is the error on the datasource if you create a new keystore?